# How to create a pandas dataframe from CSV without delimiter (in python)

Tags: python-3.x, csv, pandas

I would like to create a dataframe from a csv file that contains different columns but no delimiter.It appears that there simply are varying numbers of whitespaces between the column entries.

Also, there are some header rows at the top of the csv that contain readme information without any columns at all.

I am having trouble doing this with pd.read_csv()

Thank you!

The file looks something like this:

```
This is a header of the textfile.The header has no columns.
This is a header of the textfile.The header has no columns.
This is a header of the textfile.The header has no columns.

...
P-X1-6030-07-A01    368963
P-X1-6030-08-A01    368964
P-X1-6030-09-A01    368965
P-A-1-1011-14-G-01  368967
P-A-1-1014-01-G-05  368968
P-A-1-1017-02-D-01  368969
...
```

Comment: `pd.read_fwf(filename, header=None, skiprows=N)`, you would have to set N to number of "uninteresting rows"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have the following data file:

```
This is a header of the textfile.The header has no columns.
This is a header of the textfile.The header has no columns.
This is a header of the textfile.The header has no columns.

P X1 6030-07-A01    368963
P-X1-6030-07-A01    368963
P-X1-6030-08-A01    368964
P-X1-6030-09-A01    368965
P-A-1-1011-14-G-01  368967
P-A-1-1014-01-G-05  368968
P-A-1-1017-02-D-01  368969
```

**Solution:** let's use [read_fwf()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html) method:

```
In [192]: fn = r'D:\temp\.data\data.fwf'

In [193]: pd.read_fwf(fn, widths=[19, 7], skiprows=4, header=None)
Out[193]:
                    0       1
0    P X1 6030-07-A01  368963   # NOTE: first column has spaces ...
1    P-X1-6030-07-A01  368963
2    P-X1-6030-08-A01  368964
3    P-X1-6030-09-A01  368965
4  P-A-1-1011-14-G-01  368967
5  P-A-1-1014-01-G-05  368968
6  P-A-1-1017-02-D-01  368969
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pd.read_csv(filename, delim_whitespace=True, skiprows = number of rows to skip)
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this does not work. I did not say: sometimes the first column also containes white spaces, i.e. it can be sth like 

P X1 6030-07-A01               368963

Could that be a source of the problem?

Comment: I just modified it to not skip rows for my case and set header to none and it works perfectly in my case.